# In DB2 is there a length restriction on the SQL statement?

Tags: sql, db2

In some older versions of DB2, I know there's a limit to how many characters can be in the SQL passed to the database. (32767, I believe) -- is this the case in the latest versions of DB2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 8.2, 2MB is allowed. See: [SQL statement size limit increased to 2 MB](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/c0011594.htm)

Comment: Although this answer is still correct, version 8 is not the "latest" version of DB2.  Here are some links to the publib on DB2 limits:  [z/OS, Version 10](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.updates/src/tpc/db2z_limits.htm); [Linux/Unix/Windows, Version 9.7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html)

Comment: @galador: I said "as of" to indicate that 8.2 was the first version where the size was increased and did not mean to imply that it was the latest version.

Comment: I just included the links as informational, not trying to say it was wrong.

Comment: Of course, if you have a statement anywhere _near_ that long (even the smaller limit, usually), you may be doing something wrong.  At the very least, you're giving your DBAs headaches during maintanence.